# SBT Plugin in an unmanaged jar file

Tags: scala, sbt, unmanaged, sbt-plugin

The requirement: an SBT plugin code is in an unmanaged jar, for example in `lib/unmanaged-sbt-plugin-0.0.1.jar`. 
I was expecting the jar file would be picked up by SBT automatically and the plugin would work out-of-the-box, i.e.: the tasks would be accessible from SBT command line, but that is not the case.

The jar file has the `sbt/sbt.autoplugins` file in it and the plugin works if pulled from a remote repo into the local one and imported via `addSbtPlugin(...)`. Please note I cannot do that - it's a requirement to get it to load from the `lib/unmanaged-sbt-plugin-0.0.1.jar` and not from the local/remote repo.

Putting the following line in the `build.sbt` doesn't make the plugin work (there's not error either):

`unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/unmanaged-sbt-plugin-0.0.1.jar")`

The implementation of `addSbtPlugin(...)` is simply (according to http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Using-Plugins.html):

```
def addSbtPlugin(dependency: ModuleID): Setting[Seq[ModuleID]] =
  libraryDependencies <+= (sbtBinaryVersion in update, scalaBinaryVersion in update) 
  { (sbtV, scalaV) => sbtPluginExtra(dependency, sbtV, scalaV) }
```

I'm wondering if the above info can be used to resolve my issue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps look at [ModuleID](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.7/api/index.html#sbt.ModuleID). Something like `"my.org" % "my-plugin" % "my-version" from "file:///path/to/jar` might work (not sure - perhaps you need a .pom)

Comment: `unmanagedJars in Compile` - have you tried that _inside the plugins.sbt file in the project directory_? Basically everything in `project` is a meta-project for the base project.

Comment: I was able to make it work using this code: `addSbtPlugin("org.my-org" % "unmanaged-sbt-plugin" % "0.0.1" from "file:///./lib/unmanaged-sbt-plugin-0.0.1.jar")`! If you add the answer I'll vote it up, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you can specify an explicit URL for library dependencies (`ModuleID`):

```
addSbtPlugin("org.my-org" % "unmanaged-sbt-plugin" % "0.0.1"
  from "file:///./lib/unmanaged-sbt-plugin-0.0.1.jar")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have been struggling to get this to work.
Could not get it to work with proposed solution using `from "file://.."` (using sbt 1.0.4).

Got it to work by putting the plugin in `project/lib` folder and adding all the plugin dependencies to `plugins.sbt` using `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(..)` like in `build.sbt`. You can find the plugin dependencies by looking at the plugin pom file, usually in `.ivy2/local/<org>/<pluginname>/poms` folder.

Comment: Thanks! Putting plugin Jar under `project/lib` was enough in my case.

Comment: I just published sbt plugin with `sbt publishLocal`